Is it possible to express $\text{Li}_2(-\frac18(-i+\sqrt{15})+\text{Li}_2(\frac18 (i+\sqrt{15})$ as an explicit real expression (not numeric)?
I obtain this expression in my calculations, and numerically I am sure that it is a real number.
exp=PolyLog[2, -(1/8) I (-I + Sqrt[15])] + PolyLog[2, 1/8 I (I + Sqrt[15])];


Question.
Is it possible to express this expression as an explicit real expression (not a numeric approximation)?

It can be expressed as infinite sum of rational numbers. Does it fulfill your requirements? I doubt it can be expressed as finite expression other than it is by polylogarithm.

What for? Isn't it Mathematica for Mathematica's sake?

@azerbajdzan Thanks. If the argument of SUM will be a real function, it may help.

@user64494 Sorry, I did not understand your meaning.

@MsMath: What thing  don't you understand? Why is -0.338318939834365082073487324599 not enough?

2 Re[PolyLog[2, I/8 (I-Sqrt[15])]] is a bit simpler; but I doubt you can find anything even simpler.

The expression can be expressed as infinite sum. All the sums are pretty much the same only in different form and all produce the same terms/summands.
Sum[((-1)^n 2^(1 - n) Cos[n ArcTan[Sqrt[15]]])/
   n^2, {n, 1, ∞}] == 
  Sum[((-1)^
    n Sum[((-4)^k n (-1 - k + n)!)/(k! (-2 k + n)!), {k, 0, n/2}])/(
   n^2 2^(2 n)), {n, 1, ∞}] == 
  Sum[((-1)^n ((1/2 - (I Sqrt[15])/2)^n + (1/2 + (I Sqrt[15])/2)^n))/(
   n^2 2^(2 n)), {n, 1, ∞}] == 
  Sum[((-1)^k 2 Binomial[n, 2 k] (-(1/8))^(n - 2 k) (Sqrt[15]/8)^(
    2 k))/n^2, {n, ∞}, {k, 0, n/2}] == 
  PolyLog[2, -(1/8) - (I Sqrt[15])/8] + 
   PolyLog[2, -(1/8) + (I Sqrt[15])/8] // FullSimplify


True


So it is infinite sum of rational numbers:
Table[((-1)^n 2^(1 - n) Cos[n ArcTan[Sqrt[15]]])/n^2, {n, 1, 10}] // RootReduce
N@Total@%



The only thing now remains is to have some Euler that can express this sum as finite sum of other known real constants ;-)

Both PolyLog[2, -(1/8) I (-I + Sqrt[15])] + PolyLog[2, 1/8 I (I + Sqrt[15])] and Sum[((-1)^n ((1/2 - (I Sqrt[15])/2)^n + (1/2 + (I Sqrt[15])/2)^n))/(    n^2 2^(2 n)), {n, 1, ∞}] ==    Sum[((-1)^k 2 Binomial[n, 2 k] (-(1/8))^(n - 2 k) (Sqrt[15]/8)^(     2 k))/n^2, {n, ∞}, {k, 0, n/2}]  and so on are analytical expressions (see Wiki for the definitions). Why do you think the latter is better than the former?

Er… How do you notice this?
